# C++ operator oveload

Tags: c++

I have the following class declaration:

```
Class A
{
    A &operator =(const ACHAR *s); // (1)
    A &operator =(A &a);           // (2)
    A operator +(const ACHAR *s);  // (3)
    operator ACHAR*();             // (4)
};
```

Now, when I run this code:

```
A x,y;
ACHAR *p;
x=y; // (2)
x=y+p; (3)(4)(1)
```

The first assignment x=y invoke the (2) operator=, as expected.

But the second assignment provoke the cast operator, and the (1) operator=.

Now, since the (3) operator+ returns class A, I would expect (2) operator= to be called.

Why is this happen, and how to resolve *this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
A& operator=(A& a);
```

it should be:

```
A& operator=(const A &a);
             ^^^^^
```

In your case `y + p` produces an rvalue of type `A` which cannot be captured by non-const reference `A&`, so 4 and 1 are called instead of 2.